# Python TypeError: 'AutoField' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write field values from a Django model instance to a csv file and I'm using the following code, where `image` is an instance of the model `Image`.  I'm trying to do this without specifically naming the field names.

```
    with open(output_file, "a") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow([item.value for item in image._meta.get_field(field.name)] for field in image._meta.get_fields())
        #writer.writerow([field.name for field in Image._meta.get_fields()])
    outfile.close()
```

When I use the commented out line I get the field names which is what I expected.  I'm now trying to get the actual field values and I've got the new `writerow`.

This is giving me

> TypeError: 'AutoField' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have a double for loop. `image._meta.get_field(field.name)` returns a field, so you can't loop through it.

Once you have a field name, you can use `getattr` to get the value of that field for an item. Perhaps you want something like:

```
    writer.writerow([getattr(image, field.name) for field in image._meta.get_fields()])
```

Comment: Changed `item` to `image` which is the instance.

Comment: Good spot, fixed :)